# Integration by Parts in matrices

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

**Given Data in the question**

1. We have a given equation based on matrices as follows

$\frac{\mathrm{d} R(s)_{3\times3}}{\mathrm{d} s}=R(s)_{3\times3}K(s)_{3\times3} \tag 1$

2. $\frac{\mathrm{d} R(s)_{3\times3}}{\mathrm{d} s},K(s)$ have zero determinant and $K(s)$ is skew symmetric matrix
3. $R(s)$ is a rotation matrix.(Determinant  1, orthogonal, etc )

**Question**

1. **Can we write $\int R(s) \ ds$ using [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) rule?**

   R.H.S can be any term which includes derivatives of $K(s),R(s)$ and integral of $K(s)$ as per convenience(but no integral must of the form of product of two variable matrices,looking for simplified form,means for example  $\int R(s)_{3\times3}K(s)_{3\times3} \ ds $ has to be simplified) but it must not contain any $\int R(s) \ ds$  term. Basically I am trying to find $\int R(s) \ ds$ (L.H.S) from given relationship. Remember only $R(s)$ can be invertible rest are not